# ExecuteAsync RestSharp to allow backgroundWorker CancellationPending c#

Tags: c#, backgroundworker, blocking, kill, restsharp

I'm new to C#, RestSharp, and threading, so heres what I'm trying to do:

 I have made a program that will allow me to upload photos to tumblr, and I have the uploading working so far. Now I need the stop button to work, which I believe means I must use `ExecuteAsync()` instead of `Execute()`. 
I also have my code put in a backgroundworker, like this:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        MessageBox.Show("You pressed Cancel.");
    }
    else
    {
    var restClient = new RestClient("http://tumblr.com/api/write");
    foreach (string item in queueBox.Items)
    {
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json; //I don't know if this line is necessary
        request.AddParameter("email", usernameBox.Text);
        request.AddParameter("password", passwordBox.Text);
        request.AddParameter("type", "photo");
        request.AddFile("data", FolderName + "\\" + item);
        RestResponse response = restClient.Execute(request);
        doneBox.Invoke(new UpdateTextCallback(this.UpdateText),
            new object[] { item });
    }
    }
}
```

I believe I have set this up correctly. When I press `upload` it goes to `else` accordingly. However, I think that `RestResponse response = restClient.Execute(request);` this is blocking, which isn't allowing my code to continue checking the flag.


This is how I attempt to cancel it.

```
public void stopButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    doneBox.Items.Add("You pressed the stop button.");
    backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
}
```

Also, incase this is relevant, I have:

`public delegate void UpdateTextCallback(string item);` which allows me to call `UpdateText` and `FinishedText` as seen above in `backgroundWorker1_DoWork`.

For my question, how can I use `ExecuteAsync` in this context? I have searched but I cannot find anything that will help me, I can't find an example that is similar to my code, and since I'm new to c# I am unable to convert it to what I want.


And also, I am open to suggestions, if you see some inefficiency in my code or what not, I will be happy to accept your suggestions.


Thank you.

Comment: The odds that you see a cancel at the *start* of DoWork are zero.  Move the test inside the loop.  Might be good enough already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of potential problems here.

First, you seem to be trying to access a UI element from your background thread (as well open a MessageBox). This has a potential of throwing a CrossThread exception*.

Second, your code should look more like this:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    var restClient = new RestClient("http://tumblr.com/api/write");
    foreach (string item in queueBox.Items)
    { 
        //This should be inside the foreach 
        //as it is your loop that will check for cancel. 
        //Your code is procedural once it is in the backgroundworker
        //so it would never return to the spot you had it
        if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            //MessageBox.Show("You pressed Cancel.");
            //Removed this to the background worker completed method below
            //This avoids any UI cross thread exceptions
            return;
        }
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        //I believe Json is default for Restsharp, but you would have to play with it
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json; //I don't know if this line is necessary
        request.AddParameter("email", usernameBox.Text);
        request.AddParameter("password", passwordBox.Text);
        request.AddParameter("type", "photo");
        request.AddFile("data", FolderName + "\\" + item);
        //If you just pass in item to the below Func, it will be a closure
        //Meaning, any updates in the loop will propogate into the Action
        var newItemToAvoidClosure = item;
        //To use Async, you set up the callback method via a delegate
        //An anonymous method is as good as any here
        restClient.ExecuteAsync(request, 
            response=>
            { 
                //Maybe you should do something with the response?
                //Check the status code maybe?
                doneBox.Invoke(new UpdateTextCallback(this.UpdateText),
                    new object[] { newItemToAvoidClosure });
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Wire your background worker's `RunWorkerCompleted` method to this and perform all of your post processing here:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender,
    RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Cancelled)
        MessageBox.Show("You pressed Cancel"
}
```

Also, if you are using 4.0+, then I suggest looking into the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx). It can make your code much cleaner IMO :).

Finally, a note about the above code, what will happen is that the background worker has a high potential to return completed before all of the Rest calls complete. This will probably run fairly quick, and leave the calls still to continue as they are not cancellable in this fashion (the background worker will have already completed)(but I believe there is a way to do this for each Rest call). So, it seems to me that the real problem was that the cancellation check was in the wrong part of the code (notice I moved it inside the loop, so that it can be checked after each file was processed). You are already running in a background thread, so it seems to me that there is no point to calling another async (unless your intent is to offload the looping of the data to be sent, which then offloads the actual sending).

So, in conclusion. I provided the way to call the async, but I believe the bigger problem was that you were not checking for the cancel call appropriately.

*It may not since you are only accessing and not updating the UI element, and you did say this part was working (it probably will for the MessageBox, though)

Comment: Thanks, when I try to use this code, I get `A local variable named response cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'response' which is already used in a 'parent' or curren't scope to denote something else.`
If i change it to `                RestResponse _response = restClient.ExecuteAsync(request,
` it removes this error, but now I get `Cannot implicitly convert type RestSharp.RestRequestAsyncHandle' to 'RestSharp.RestResponse'`

Comment: I changed it to `var _response`, but it doesn't actually upload, it simply prints the `UpdateText` to the `doneBox`. Like, I know that it's not even trying to upload because it goes through the script in literally 1 second.

Comment: Juding by `MessageBox.Show(response.ResponseStatus.ToString());`, I'm getting `Timed out` for every single request.

Comment: @Anteara I have updated my answer to remove storing the response of the async call (as you really wont need it here). Also, I have added a suggestion to use the RunWorkerCompleted to better deal with potential UI processing errors. Last, you can set your client's Timeout to a higher value (I am not sure of the default) to fix your current issue of timing out. However, it seems that this has resolved your initial question. If that is true, upvotes and accepted answers are always appreciated :)

Comment: Thank you, I'm having trouble finding documentation on how to set the timeout for `ExecuteAsync`. I found `Execute` documentation on setting timeout, but not `ExecuteAsync`. I feel like there is limited documentation for restSharp, or perhaps I'm not looking in the right places.
Can you help figure out how to set the timeout?
Thanks.

Comment: @Anteara Well, it is open source, so you can just read the code :) I did, and the timeout is supposed to be set up the same way that you would for a synchronous action...RestClient.Timeout If you have old code, this was a bug that was not merged in until ~1 year ago, though

Comment: This is ridiculous, I don't understand why this isnt working.`var restClient = new RestClient("http://tumblr.com/api/write");
            restClient.Timeout = 10000;`

Neither this nor

`response =>
{
restClient.Timeout = 10000;`

works. It just doesn't do anything, there is no difference between it being there and it not there. It doesn't matter how large or small the number is.

Comment: The underlying request uses HttpWebRequest. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.timeout.aspx   States that the Timeout is in milliseconds, so you are only setting the timeout to 10 seconds.

Comment: I know, as I said it doesn't matter how large or small the number is, I set it to 100,000 too, and as I stated it does the same thing.
However, I tried to send a simple "regular" (basically a plain text post) request to the tumblr api, and It was successfull which means perhaps I am reading the file wrong?

Comment: Perhaps. Check Fiddler to see what is actually being sent maybe? Another suggestion would be to put a 60 second sleep before the background worker returns. Just to make sure that this is not from the instances being destroyed...which I doubt as they should be on a different context, but it never hurts to try everything when debugging...assume nothing. It does sound like it could be the file though...best of luck, and I would suggest opening a new question if this problem does persist :) Maybe somebody will have run into it in the past.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your help. I searched the source and got it working by doing this:`byte[] byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(FolderName + "\\" + item);` and
`request.AddFile("data", byteArray, FolderName + "\\" + item);`
To be honest I don't know why this fixes it, but it does :D.

Comment: @Anteara Hrmm, just looked at the code, and it looked like it should work...looking at it further :)

Comment: My guess is it might have to do with the StreamReader? Definitely interesting. But, your working code is getting the data in a different manner...that would explain why one works and another doesnt