# backgroundWorker exits as soon as starts, plus continues after cancel

Tags: c#, asynchronous, upload, backgroundworker, terminate

I'm having a lot of trouble with my background worker. I have a background worker to upload pictures (sometimes over 100) to tumblr. Naturally, this is extremely repetitive.

 
My problems are this: 

1) As soon or a few seconds after I start my thread, `backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted` is called, as shown by it printing the text within that method/event.

2) When I cancel the thread, it calls `backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted`, as shown by it printing the text within it, however, files continue to keep uploading. It seems like the thread still exists.


 I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, I've been searching for the past few days and tried so many different methods. Here is my code:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
    var restClient = new RestClient("http://tumblr.com/api/write");
    foreach (string item in queueBox.Items)
    {
        if (!backgroundWorker.CancellationPending)
        {
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            request.AddParameter("email", usernameBox.Text);
            request.AddParameter("password", passwordBox.Text);
            request.AddParameter("type", "photo");
            byte[] byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(FolderName + "\\" + item);
            request.AddFile("data", byteArray, FolderName + "\\" + item);
            var newItemToAvoidClosure = item;
            restClient.ExecuteAsync(request, response => { doneBox.Invoke(new UpdateTextCallback(this.UpdateText), new object[] { newItemToAvoidClosure }); });
        }
        else
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my `RunWorkerCompleted`

```
private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!(e.Cancelled))
    { //if not cancelled
        if (!(e.Error == null))
        { //if above true, see if theres an error

            doneBox.Items.Add("\r\nAn Error Ocurred: " + e.Error.Message + "\r\n. However, what you uploaded may have been successful up until this error." );
        }
        else
        { //else there is no error which means it was 100% successful
            doneBox.Items.Add("Finished uploading! Go and check out your stuff on Tumblr! ^_^" );
        }
    }
    else //else the user DID press cancel
    {
        doneBox.Items.Add("You pressed Cancel - However, the photos before you pressed cancel have been uploaded." );
    }
}
```

Now, i'll try and explain what I think is happening in my `DoWork`,
since the for loop is what loops each photo upload, the if statement is in there so it can constantly check if cancellationpending is true. If it is, set e.Cancel to true to end the thread.
Also, I'm using ExecuteAsync to upload, so I was hoping I would be able to terminate the thread mid upload, so that photo doesn't upload.


 Okay, I'm sorry, I know that this has been discussed before. I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong though.

By the way, this is how I attempt to cancel:

```
public void stopButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    doneBox.Items.Add("You pressed the stop button.");
        backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
}
```

Thank you all.

Comment: As long as you are using ExecuteAsync() you have no use for a BackgroundWorker.  Use Execute() instead so you can actually cancel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things:

Firstly, you're trying to access the UI from the background worker:

```
request.AddParameter("email", usernameBox.Text);
```

You shouldn't do that. It sounds like you should be setting up all the information the background worker needs first, *then* starting it.

Secondly, the fact that you're calling `ExecuteAsync` is exactly why your background worker is completing immediately, but then the files are continuing to upload. You're basically queueing a load of work for the rest client to do asynchronously.

While are you using `ExecuteAsync` in the first place? You're already within a background thread - why not just do the work synchronously?

Comment: Well it was to my knowledge that `Execute` would block and I would be unable to end uploading MID UPLOAD. So you're saying this is possible simply by using `Execute`?

Comment: @Anteara: You probably won't be able to quit it mid-upload, but the way you're doing it at the moment is trying starting *all* the uploads at basically the same time, and you haven't got any way of cancelling it anyway. At least if you made each request synchronously you'd be able to stop at the right time. I don't know `RestClient` well enough to know its cancellation strategy, but I would say that "synchronously in the background" would at least be better than your current approach.

Comment: @Anteara This answer is what I was trying to say in my original answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9833813/executeasync-restsharp-to-allow-backgroundworker-cancellationpending-c-sharp in the "Finally, a note about the above code" section. You did move the if check into the for loop, but you ended up keeping the async call, which is why you did end up with this problem :) BTW, if you want to make each call separately cancellable, then you can store each RestRequestAsyncHandle that is returned and call its Abort method